# Hierarchicaly Appending DOM elements with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am working on creating a portfolio website for myself. In order to expedite the process for adding more photos and maintaining it automatically that way as opposed to adding new HTML each time, I am in the process of creating a script in order to automatically add a specified folder's image contents to the gallery.

I found a template that I am using which works well for the barebones starter website, and am currently in the process of customizing it to suit my needs better.

The template they use for maintaining the fluid-box / gallery which allows for image filtering based on topic etc. etc. is as follows:

```
<div class="item landscape col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 mb-4">
        <a href="images/landscape/land_01.jpg" class="item-wrap fancybox">
          <span class="icon-search2"></span>
          <img class="img-fluid" src="images/landscape/land_01.jpg">
        </a>
</div>
```

Where I can specify the second class tag to determine how it is filtered, and I update the `href` of the link and the `src` of the image in order to set it to which ever photo is next in the folder.

Right now however I am running into issues with getting my Javascript to create a element with this hierarchy. Currently the script I have designed looks like this:

```
var outer = document.createElement("div");
outer.className = "item landscape col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 mb-4";

var reference = document.createElement('a');
reference.href = "images/landscape/land_02.jpg";
reference.className = "item-wrap fancybox";
reference.innerHTML = "Test";

var spanner = document.createElement("SPAN");
spanner.className = "icon-search2";

var thepic = document.createElement("IMG");
thepic.className = "img-fluid";
thepic.src = "images/landscape/land_02.jpg";

reference.appendChild("spanner");
reference.appendChild("thepic");
outer.appendChild("reference");

var container = document.getElementById("posts");
container.appendChild(thepic);
```

However this consistently gives me the error `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.` I have researched this bug and when I simplified the script to just append a link to the container element this worked, however whenever I try to append to the DOM elements I am attempting to create with Javascript it is failing.

I would appreciate any help you guys can give!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems with your code.

First, when referencing variables you're using a string with their names. Which is wrong, you can and should just use it without quotes. Like so:

```
reference.appendChild("spanner");
reference.appendChild("thepic");
outer.appendChild("reference");
```

should be

```
reference.appendChild(spanner);
reference.appendChild(thepic);
outer.appendChild(reference);
```

Second, more importantly, you're should probably use some templating engine to do that sort of stuff. Changing it by hand will become cumbersome very fast. You don't have to use modern and fancy frameworks (like React, Angular, Vue, etc) to do that right. You can just check something like https://github.com/janl/mustache.js for example or https://ejs.co/ to make your life easier.

Comment: Wow, can't believe I missed something so simple thanks for that!  

The mustache template software looks very useful. I knew about components with React, but did not want to get too fancy with JS for such a simple site. I will look into using that thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With multi line strings and variable interpolation, you can use your HTML directly in your code. The method to insert it is `insertAdjacentHTML`.

```js
const clss = "landscape";
const src = "images/landscape/land_01.jpg";
const href = "images/landscape/land_01.jpg";

const html = `<div class="item ${clss} col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 mb-4">
        <a href="${href}" class="item-wrap fancybox">
          <span class="icon-search2"></span>
          <img class="img-fluid" src="${src}">
        </a>
</div>`

const container = document.getElementById("container");
container.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", html);
alert(container.outerHTML);
```

```html
<div id="container">the container</div>
```

Comment: This is also really useful. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I'd suggest avoiding libraries when native code can do what you want. These days, there's little barrier to going mostly native.